# How to add several button in stack panel with spaces between buttons

Tags: wpf, button, alignment, stackpanel

I try to put several buttons in `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,590,1,-40"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.25,0.964">
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,590,10,-40" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.25,0.964">
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

All my `Buttons` alignment to the right side which is OK but with no spaces between them.

Any suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: add margins to your buttons

Comment: Add *better* margins to your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Margin property....

Default is Left, Top, Right, Bottom, so in your sample code you have Left = 10, Top = 590, Right = 1, and Bottom = -40.

Change the Left/Right Margins to something reasonable. Here's some (cleaned up) example code :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Add" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @getwewe So set the VerticalAlignment to Bottom. You always want to use your panels to lay out your controls correctly, and not use excessive Margins.